# Sqoop import to route records with null values in a particular columns into another table

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to move records with null values in a particular column to a particular table and non-null records to another while SQOOP import. tried to explore on goolge but there is not much beyond --null-string and --null-non-String params but that will just replace with the defined characters ...

I can think of following ways to handle it

1. once importing into hive, run a dedup to filter out the records but this is something to be tried in worst case.
2. handling at sqoop level itself(no clue on this)

could any expert here can help me with the above ask.

ENV details : its a plain Apache hadoop cluster. sqoop version 1.4.6

Answer (score 0):

We can try making use of `--query` option along with the `sqoop-import` command

```
--query select * from table where column is null and  $CONDITIONS
```

And in a similar way for not null condition also.

There will be 2 sqoop import jobs here.